# Is it possible to organize data between elasticsearch shards based on stored data?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to build a data store with three nodes. The first one should keep all data, the second one data of the last month, the third data of the last week. Is it possible to automatically configure elasticsearch shards to relocate themselves between nodes so that this functionality is given?

Comment: can indexing data based on created_at, i meant was to create indices based on date-time i.e week in this case and then move/rolling the document indices every week

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move existing documents from some node to another then you can use `_cluster/reroute`.
But using this solution with automatic allocation can be dangerous as just after moving an index to target node it will try to even balance the cluster.

Or you can disable automatic allocations, in that case, only custom allocations will work and can be really risky to handle for large data set.

```
    POST /_cluster/reroute
{
    "commands" : [
        {
            "move" : {
                "index" : "test", "shard" : 0,
                "from_node" : "node1", "to_node" : "node2"
            }
        },
        {
          "allocate_replica" : {
                "index" : "test", "shard" : 1,
                "node" : "node3"
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

source: [Elasticsearch rerouting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/cluster-reroute.html)

Also, you should read this : > [Customize document routing](https://www.elastic.co/blog/customizing-your-document-routing)

Comment: Not exactly what we are searching for but a good start. We want to use a mobile server off-site which is supposed to hold only the latest data. Once it is back in the network, it should sync the new data to the main storage and the replicas. Also it would be nice to define something like: "Off-site: only keep data not older than two weeks" or something like this

Comment: I am also relatively new to EK stack so don't have idea if we can implement your first requirement (sync an off-site server automatically) but you can use 'curator' to keep relatively new data (purge data older than 2 weeks).

Comment: And this blog post: https://www.elastic.co/blog/hot-warm-architecture-in-elasticsearch-5-x